# PHP Creating an array from an array and looping through

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code:

```
foreach ($row as $item) {
  if (!in_array($item['login_id'], $tmp)) {
    $tmp[] = $item['brand'];
    $tmp[] = $item['login_id'];
    $tmp[] = $item['name'];
  }
}
```

This provides the following output:

```
array(408) { 
 [0]=> string(4) "ABC" 
 [1]=> string(8) "r4ft6tg7" 
 [2]=> string(8) "Aberdeen" 
 [3]=> string(4) "ABC" 
 [4]=> string(8) "1ws3edft" 
 [5]=> string(18) "Birmingham Airport" 
 [6]=> string(4) "DDD" 
 [7]=> string(8) "bgt6yhnj" 
 [8]=> string(27) "Birmingham City"...}
```

I am trying to then loop through this array and add them to a dropdown using the following:

```
$a = 0;
$b = 1;
$c = 2;

foreach ($tmp as $value) {
    echo "<option name='".$value[$a]."' 
          value='".$value[$b]."'>
          ".$value[$c]."
          </option>";
$a=$a+3;
$b=$b+3;
$c=$c+3;
}
```

However the output is most odd:

```
<option name='I' value='b'>i</option>
```

The output I expected and need is:

```
<option name='ABC' value='r4ft6tg7'>Aberdeen</option>
```

Any suggestions, feedback on where I am going wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: `$value` is a string, so accessing `$value[$x]` will yield whatever character is at that index in the string...what are you trying to accomplish exactly? What are `$a`, `$b` and `$c` for?

Comment: Ah, I am trying to place the vales of what I thought we array elemens into the `option` output.  So for example, `<option name='ABC' value='r4ft6tg7'>Aberdeen</option>`

Comment: @Clive - thanks for that, much appreciated.  I didn't realise it was a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you meant:

```
foreach ($row as $item) {
  if (! array_key_exists($item['login_id'], $tmp)) {
    $tmp[$item['login_id']] = array($item['brand'], $item['login_id'], $item['name']);
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** Fixed index of `$tmp` above (and how to check for index).

Then your following code could work the same, omitting the increments of `$a`, `$b`, `$c` (and hence omitting those three variables altogether):

```
foreach ($tmp as $value) {
    echo "<option name='".$value[0]."' 
          value='".$value[1]."'>
          ".$value[2]."
          </option>";
}
```

You were mistakenly treating `$tmp` as both a one- and two-dimensional array.  Actually setting it up to be a two-dimensional array resolves that.  As pointed out in the comments, in your original code, `$value` was a string, and accessing an index of a string like you would an array yields the given character in the string.

Also, for clarity, you might consider making each subarray in `$tmp` an asssociative array.
E.g.
`$tmp[$item['login_id']] = array('brand' => $item['brand'], ...` and then accessing it accordingly in your latter `foreach` loop.

Comment: Should `$tmp[$item['login_id']] = array($item['brand'], $item['login_id'], $item['name'];)' actually be `$tmp[$item['login_id']] = array($item['brand'], $item['login_id'], $item['name']);` - semi-colonin the wrong place?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, my bad. Thanks.

Comment: No probs - thanks for the help.  Although I'm still not getting the output I expect.

Comment: I am now :-)  perfect, thanks - that is exactly what I was after!

Comment: Hmm... did you see my edit to use `array_key_exists` in place of `in_array`?

Comment: Spotted it - can I ask why?

Comment: `in_array` worked for your 1-dimensional array approach (so long as you had no other data that could have the same value as one of your login IDs).  But since the login ID seems to be the value uniquely identifying each row, it makes sense to index the array by that value. Hence now it's the key and so check for the key instead of an array element.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  Much appreciated and makes perfect sense.